# how to get data from multidimensional array without any key Value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have one multi-dimensional array. I want  Id which is added without any key value. i want a key value which like "566934ae-879a-58cb" how can I get that Id? in javascript.

```
var data = [{
        "7acafaa5-f276-9094": {
            "name": "kaa",
            "number": "46645",
            "city": "Surat",
            "hobby": "hockey",
            "birthdate": "2017-06-21"
        },
        "566934ae-879a-58cb": {
            "name": "Karrgi",
            "number": "096013",
            "city": "Ahmedabad",
            "hobby": "hockey",
            "birthdate": "2017-06-15"
        },
        "365867ca-9f09-367b": {
            "name": "Karnaargi",
            "number": "06013",
            "city": "Ahmedabad",
            "hobby": "hockey",
            "birthdate": "2017-06-15"
        }
    }
]
```

I have to get all id's(Keys) from the array which are added in the one table

Comment: try using a for in loop

Comment: Is this `7acafaa5-f276-9094` the id?

Comment: like this: `for (key in data[0]) {/*Code here. key contains your key value. so you can access your object like this data[0][key]*/}`

Comment: get data using index

Comment: Do you add the item with any of the Array methods?

Comment: yes this is the id and i want to get all data with the help of this id to add data to table and edit the data also

Comment: i just use this code but not successed  

function getData(){
 var getdata = localStorage.getItem('karnav');
 var obj = JSON.parse(getdata);
 for(var i = 0; i < obj[0].length; i++){
  console.log(obj[0][i]); 
 }
 }
 getData();

get me undefined

Comment: @KARNAVPARGI check my snippet by running it. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), As the object is an array use index to access array element then the method can be used.

```
console.log(Object.keys(data[0]))
```

```js
var data = [{
  "7acafaa5-f276-9094": {
    "name": "kaa",
    "number": "46645",
    "city": "Surat",
    "hobby": "hockey",
    "birthdate": "2017-06-21"
  },
  "566934ae-879a-58cb": {
    "name": "Karnav B Pargi",
    "number": "09601096013",
    "city": "Ahmedabad",
    "hobby": "hockey",
    "birthdate": "2017-06-15"
  },
  "365867ca-9f09-367b": {
    "name": "Karnav B Pargi",
    "number": "09601096013",
    "city": "Ahmedabad",
    "hobby": "hockey",
    "birthdate": "2017-06-15"
  }
}];
console.log(Object.keys(data[0]))
```

Comment: this works i get all keys from it but now i have to get all data which are added in all that key how can i get all data and show???

Comment: @KARNAVPARGI, What do you mean by all data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce function and collect the keys and create a map such that you can use those keys to get that data.

```js
var data = [{
  "7acafaa5-f276-9094": {
    "name": "kaa",
    "number": "46645",
    "city": "Surat",
    "hobby": "hockey",
    "birthdate": "2017-06-21"
  },
  "566934ae-879a-58cb": {
    "name": "Karnav B Pargi",
    "number": "09601096013",
    "city": "Ahmedabad",
    "hobby": "hockey",
    "birthdate": "2017-06-15"
  },
  "365867ca-9f09-367b": {
    "name": "Karnav B Pargi",
    "number": "09601096013",
    "city": "Ahmedabad",
    "hobby": "hockey",
    "birthdate": "2017-06-15"
  }
}];

var idToProfileMap = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(val);
  keys.forEach(k => {
    acc[k] = val[k];
  })
  return acc;
}, {});

// get all keys
const allIds = Object.keys(idToProfileMap);
console.log(Object.keys(idToProfileMap));

// get data using the first key
console.log(idToProfileMap[allIds[0]])
```

The code above will also work if data has more than one element.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the `data` array to get specific id data and then loop through id object to get it's properties

```js
    var data = [{
            "7acafaa5-f276-9094": {
                "name": "kaa",
                "number": "46645",
                "city": "Surat",
                "hobby": "hockey",
                "birthdate": "2017-06-21"
            },
            "566934ae-879a-58cb": {
                "name": "Karnav B Pargi",
                "number": "09601096013",
                "city": "Ahmedabad",
                "hobby": "hockey",
                "birthdate": "2017-06-15"
            },
            "365867ca-9f09-367b": {
                "name": "Karnav B Pargi",
                "number": "09601096013",
                "city": "Ahmedabad",
                "hobby": "hockey",
                "birthdate": "2017-06-15"
            }
        }
    ];
    
    data.forEach(function(id){
         // Get the data of particular id. You can loop over the specific id to access it's properties
         Object.keys(id).forEach(function(prop){
             console.log(id[prop]);
         })
    })
```